# How to reload a div content without reloading the whole page after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

what i want to achieve is to reload the content of a div on a page without reloading the whole page, I want to reload the div to after photo upload so the newly uploaded photo can be loaded from the database but i don't want to reload the whole page, but the code was not working instead i got the whole page loading into the div likr below
    function ajaxLoad(){

```
     var loadUrl = window.location.href;
    // $(".carouser-inner ").load(loadUrl);
     $(".carouser-inner ").load(loadUrl+".carouser-inner ");
}
```

I call the function after ajax is successful, but below is what i got

WHAT I WANTED[image: THIS IS WHAT I'D WANTED TO ACHIEVE AND THE ID FROM THE DATA EMBEDED ALREADY]

But below is what i got, and after i reload the page it now go back to normal as i wanted
[image]

Any help on how to achieve this will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: what do you expect? `window.location.href` is a current page url and you use it for ajax call. Of cource you get the whole current page in response. You should create separate url that will return you only html for your gallery

Comment: could post the code for displaying the image? if I didn't misunderstand the question, you shall get the new image path which returns from ajax, then set the new path to the image.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation of jQuery's .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), you need a space between the url and the selector, so:

`$(".carouser-inner ").load(loadUrl+" .carouser-inner");`

Answer (score 0):

First clear the div, then set the div's contents. You can clear it with a function, maybe `clearDiv()` or simply set `.innerHTML = ""` if that's all you need to do.

Fetching content with AJAX/XHR/Fetch is going to be asynchronous so you will need to architect that as a `.Promise` and resolve it `.then` set the content.

Comment: Thank you guys, i've been trying to figure it out but still i can't make it work, i still get the whole page loaded or when i add a space at the back of the url as suggested by @forsureitsme i will get empty div and nothing show up in it except i reload again, please anyone can help with a demo, thanks

Answer (score 0):

this completely depends on what the url you are calling with load() returns. It seems your url used in load() is returning the entire page's HTML.

Instead you want the url you use with load() to return just your html portion you want to load into the div

so there is no problem with your jquery call, it's the value returned by the url used with load() that needs to be fixed. That is a server-side question, nothing to do with the jquery code.

So, in brief: your fix is to fix the url used with load(), just make it return the partial html you want

HTH